# Using javascript to create Jquery link

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a dynamic adbanner which is loaded onto websites via Google Double Click.

We use some Jquery in the code so as part of the set up we check if a website is running Jquery and if not we use Javascript to add a link to our Jquery file.

This is being done fine however I'm still getting an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" I'd assume this is due to the order things are loading in but I'm not sure how to get around the issue.  Everything works fine if you refresh the page the problem only seems to happen on first load.

Also if I open a new browser window and load the page a second time everything works fine.

Here's the code we are using to add the script tags to the head:

```
if(!window.jQuery)
 {

    var fm_j = document.createElement('script'); fm_j.type = 'text/javascript';
    fm_j.src = 'js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fm_j);
 }
```

Comment: are you adding the cdn??

Comment: _"we check if a website is running Jquery and if not we use Javascript to add a link to our Jquery file"_ - Is that wise? What if the page does have jQuery already so you don't add your own, but the version already included is too old or new to be compatible with your code?

Comment: use typeof, `if(typeof(jQuery) === "undefined")`

Comment: Simply appending some string with "`<script>`" in it won't load the whole script, bear that in mind

Comment: `if(typeof window.jQuery == "undefined"){ … }`

Comment: Wouldn't such an ad be inserted as an iFrame ?

Comment: Messiah sorry I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: nnnnn we've tried that most of the time it's fine but we find that our Jquery file sometimes causes issues on the website... the jquery we use is pretty standard stuff though so it should work with any version of jquery unless it's really really old.

Comment: You're loading 80KB and tens of thousands of JS code for a banner -_-?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum sounds like : Splat them jQueriess!

Comment: for shame. adding 80k. that's almost half an icon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a timing issue. When you load scripts dynamically like that, they are loaded asynchronously and don't block further execution of javascript on the page. This means that jQuery may not be loaded by the time your jQuery specific code is being run.

When you refresh, `js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js` has probably been cached and so will load faster, so you don't see errors.

The solution is to wrap your javascript into a function that is called once jQuery has loaded using a `load` event handler. Here's an example I adapted from [this tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/load-jquery-only-if-not-present/).

[**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rq5T6/).

```
function getScript(success) {

    var fm_j = document.createElement('script'); 
        fm_j.type = 'text/javascript';
        fm_j.src = 'js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js',
        done = false;

    // Attach handlers for all browsers
    fm_j.onload = fm_j.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {

            done = true;
            // callback function provided as param
            success();
        };
    };

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fm_j);
};

if(!window.jQuery) {
    getScript(doSomething);
} else {
    doSomething();
}
```

Also, as several commentors pointed out, many sites place banner ads inside iframes to keep the ads from "polluting" your page with their libraries.

Answer (score 0):

iFrame could have been a better way to go @flyersun

It's simple and easy and effective, see here

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272246